# Input from command line

Tags: c++, command-line-arguments

I have a program in C++ which I run for many values of a parameter. What I want to do is the following:
Let's say I have two parameters as:

```
int main(){
    double a;
    double b;
//some more lines of codes
}
```

Now after after I compile I want to run it as

```
./output.out 2.2 5.4
```

So that `a` takes the value 2.2 and `b` takes the value 5.4.

Of course one way is to use `cin>>` but I cannot do that because I run the program on a cluster.

Comment: Why don't use command line arguments (i.e., argv ) ? Of course you have to convert them later to `double` type.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to use [*command line arguments*](http://www.site.uottawa.ca/~lucia/courses/2131-05/labs/Lab3/CommandLineArguments.html) in your `main`:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    if (argc != 3) return -1;
    double a = atof(argv[1]);
    double b = atof(argv[2]);
    ...
    return 0;
}
```

This code parses parameters using [`atof`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/atof/); you could use [`stringstream`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/stringstream/) instead.

Comment: Don't use `const char *argv[]`, just use `char *argv[]`, -1 until fixed.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII This is now fixed.

Answer (score 11):

If you want to use command line parameters then no, you *don't* use `cin` as it is too late.  You need to change your `main` signature to:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    // argc is the argument count
    // argv contains the arguments "2.2" and "5.4"
}
```

So you now have `argv` which is an array of pointer to `char`, each pointer pointing to an argument that was passed.  The first argument is typically the path to your executable, subsequent arguments are whatever was passed in when your application was launched, in the form of pointers to `char`.

You will need to convert the `char*`'s to `double`s in this case.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that is's `int argc`, not `size_t`. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Linuxios: Yeah you're right.  Some compilers allow `size_t`, but the standard only mandates that `int main()` and `int main(int, char*[])` be accepted, anything else is implementation defined (well, the C++98 standard that I have lying around anyway...)

Answer (score 4):

That's what command-line arguments are for:

```
#include <sstream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argv < 3)
       // show error
    double a, b;

    std::string input = argv[1];
    std::stringstream ss = std::stringstream(input);

    ss >> a;

    input = argv[2];
    ss = std::stringstream(input);

    ss >> b;

    // a and b are now both successfully parsed in the application
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at [boost program options](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/doc/html/program_options.html)?

It will take the command line arguments like many other are suggesting and let you provide a very consistent, clean and extensible command line interface.

Comment: If you are already using boost then yeah, it's nice, but I wouldn't include boost into an application just to parse a few simple command line arguments.

Comment: I've always found that argument parsing starts out simple, and quickly gets out of hand introducing subtle bugs and constraints as the tool grows.

Comment: I guess it depends on how complex your arguments can be.  For simple [switch value] type args I have never had a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this form of the `main()` function to get command line arguments

```
    int main(int argc, char* argv[]) { 

    }
```

where the values of the `argv[]` array contain your command line variables as `char*` that you will need to convert to `floats` or `doubles` in your case