# to parse command line arguments in c++ class

Tags: c++

I am new to c++ ,I am going to add some functions to my class which could be run in console app..for example if I add /pstat -help it runs info(); function..and things like that..
I have searvhed a lot about c++ but there is not any help or examples for this..Could you please give me some hints?

I have tried this method  in main()

```
  int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {


 if (argv== "-info"){
 info();
 return 1;
 }else{
 pidstat(argc, argv);
 }

 return 0;

}
```

I want whan a user inputs `./procstat -info` it runs `info()` and when user inputs `./procstat 1` it runs `pidstat(argc, argv);`
How is it possible?
thank you

Comment: It's totally unclear what you're asking. What functions? For what purpose? Where?

Comment: What's the problem? Are you asking how to parse command line arguments and have your program perform different operations depending on what those arguments are? Where did you get this huge code dump from?

Comment: @cad I have updated my question..sorry for my unclear question

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit sorry,I have updated my question..This is exactly what you said..thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Input from command line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11315854/input-from-command-line)

Comment: _Much_ better now, though I'm afraid the only useful response here is "learn how to program C++ and do some research", because we don't do it for you here...

Answer (score 1):

The parameter `argv` uses C-Style strings so you can't compare using `operator==`.

Either use the C-style string functions, `strcmp, strncmp, str*()`, or convert to a `std::string` and use the comparison operators.

FYI, you are actually comparing the values in pointers, not the contents of what they point to.